# Where is the function x|x-y| totally differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

For what $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is the function
$$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}:(x,y) \mapsto x|x-y|$$
totally differentiable?

Certainly, for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x\neq y$ the function will be totally differentiable. However, I'm doubting about the case when $x=y$. Because the absolute value $|\cdot|$ is not differentiable at $0$, we can expect that $f$ will not be totally differentiable for $x=y\neq 0$. However, because the function $x\mapsto x|x|$ is differentiable at $x=0$ I expect the function $f$ to be totally differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: The question need some corrections. What is the domain of $f$? $\mathbb R $ or $\mathbb R ^{2}$.

Comment: The map is not $x \to x|x-y|$. It is $(x,y) \to x|x-y|$.

Comment: The "reasoning" is not correct, because it is not entirely reasoning. It is a feeling, or expectation, or intuition–informed by reasoning. Good intuition though.

Comment: You're correct, this is more like an intuition about what I expect about the differentiability of the function. I know how to formalize this idea but I wanted to be sure about the intuition. So the intuitive idea is correct?

Comment: The intuitive idea is correct. You could formalize it by computing the total derivative of $f$ and showing that it indeed exists for $(0,0)$ but not on $\{(x,x)\in\mathbb R^2:x\ne 0\}$.

Comment: @Math1000 Ok, so the formal answer I give below is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is totally differentiable for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq y$ because $f$ is partially differentiable and the partial derivatives 
\begin{align} \partial_xf &= |x-y|+\frac{x(x-y)}{|x-y|}\\
\partial_y f &= \frac{x(y-x)}{|x-y|}
\end{align}
are continuous for $x\neq y$.
For $x=y\neq 0$ we have that $f$ is not partially differentiable. Hence, the only case left is when $x=y=0$. In that case, the partial derivatives are no longer continuous and thus the total derivative should be calculated explicitly. We have that $(\partial_x f)(0,0) =(\partial_y f)(0,0) = 0$ and $f(0,0)=0$. So we need to verify if the limit
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{||f(x,y)||}{||(x,y)||}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x|x-y|}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$$
is zero. Indeed, note that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x|x-y| =\lim_{t\to0} t|t|$. Hence the limit above is equivalent to 
$$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{t|t|}{\sqrt{2}|t|}=0,$$
which proves the differentiability of $f$ in $x=y=0$.